# How to set rank per group with a SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank

Please first refer to the table structure:
[image]

Now you could see there is one unique constraint including `manager_code, archive_year and archive_day_of_year`.

I need to rank the managers for every group which members having the same branch_code, year and day of year. Here `branch_code` stands for the department code.

I tried this:
[image: query to get rank]
[image: rank result in one group]

I could get the correct rank number using `RANK()` on SQL Server but I don't know how to set the correct_rank back into the rank_in_department column using an `UPDATE` statement on table `open_account_by_manager_per_day`.

Do you have any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### CTE:

You can embed you `SELECT` with `RANK()` into a CTE and then `UPDATE` the CTE.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, r = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY archive_day, archive_year, branch_code ORDER BY open_count)
    FROM @data
)
UPDATE c 
SET rank_in_department = r 
FROM cte c;
```

Don't forget the `;` terminator at the end of the line preceding the CTE statement.

#### Sub Query:

You can also self `JOIN` your table on a sub query with the expected `RANK`.

```
UPDATE d SET rank_in_department = r.r
FROM @data d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
        , r = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY archive_day, archive_year, branch_code ORDER BY open_count) 
    FROM @data
) r ON d.id = r.id
```

This query expects an `Id` or a group of column in both the sub query and the `JOIN`. It is used to uniquely identify each row and `JOIN` it to the table. From your data in your sample picture, this seems to be `manager_code+, archive_year, archive_day_of_year`

#### Sample Data used:

This gives your 2 correct syntaxes using this sample data. Queries must be adapted to your real table(s).

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(id int identity(0, 1), archive_year int, archive_day int, branch_code nvarchar(5), rank_in_department int, open_count int)
INSERT INTO @data(archive_day, archive_year, branch_code, open_count) VALUES
    (2016, 1, 'X', 5)
    , (2016, 1, 'X', 15)
    , (2016, 1, 'X', 52)
    , (2016, 1, 'X', 36)
    , (2016, 1, 'X', 55)
    , (2016, 1, 'Y', 65)
    , (2016, 1, 'Y', 85)
    , (2016, 1, 'Y', 42)
    , (2016, 1, 'Y', 96)
    , (2016, 1, 'Y', 15);

SELECT *
    , r = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY archive_day, archive_year, branch_code ORDER BY open_count)
FROM @data;
```